# Components are inhering CSS from other components

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having an issue with my components:
1. For some reason I am not able to style html and body in signin.component.css
The solution I found was using:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None ==> This works perfect
```

However when I change the view, example: home the signin.component.css is being inherited into the home component.

Is there something wrong with it? Or does anyone knows how to style html and body in css components?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue by myself,

Thanks to all who helped me out.

The problem was that it's not possible edit html and body html tags in component css. The right way to do this is removing the ViewEncapsultation and add the following lines of code into the constructor.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'../../../assets/images/background.jpg\')';
document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
document.body.style.height = '100%';
```

This is how you can style html and body tags in every component. 
This also works if you need to style the whole background.

Comment: you are not supposed to access DOM like that in Angular. Also you should have explained the problem properly e.g. why are you trying to apply global styles in a component!

Answer (score 0):

Changing encapsulation is rarely a good thing to do.
I'd create a state service that changes classes and styles upon components.

It should look something like this

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StyleService {
    private className: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
    public className$: Observable<string> = this.className.asObservable();

    set(className: string): any {
        this.className.next(className);
    }
}
```

In order to listen to changes

```
...
private sub: Subscription;
...
this.sub = this.styleService.className$
    .subscribe(class => {
        // do what you need to do
    })
...
ngOnDestroy() {
    // so you dont have memory leaks
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

When you want to change the class you simple call the set function.
The only thing that is missing is declaring the classes in the main styling file.

If you need to have a className initial value you can use BehaviorSubject like the following:

```
private class: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('className');
```